# Failed to query NamespaceRegistry for isNamespaceRegistered. (all worked just 50 days ago)

Tags: salesforcedx

I am able to log into my partnerorg then I attempt to create a scratchorg

```
 sfdx force:org:create -f \config\\project-scratch-def.json -a mydemodemo --durationdays 30;
```

this worked just 50 days ago and have created dozens of scratch orgs before on this same partner org.   But today I am getting

```
ERROR:  Worker NamespaceRegistryValidator threw an unhandled exception. Failed to query NamespaceRegistry for isNamespaceRegistered.
```

I am at a loss for what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

The account has to have `Read` object permissions for `Namespace Registries`.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out if you get this answer it is because the account you are authenticating with is not an admin account.   Our org took us down to two licenses and forgot to tell me